# Allowing access to the Google Admin SDK Directory API in Python

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I'm trying to setup a google group for marketing purposes, in which when certain users sign up to my application, I send their email to this google group with the following code

```
# google_admin_apis.py
def add_member(member):
    if not member.email:
        return False
    try:
        service = build('admin', 'directory_v1')
    except DefaultCredentialsError: # For developers
        return False
    group_key = 'mygroup@mydomain.com'
    body = {
        "email": member.email
    }
    members = service.members()
    request = members.insert(groupKey=group_key, body=body)
    response = request.execute()
    return True
```

My application is hosted on Google App Engine, so by default [ADC will use the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) when run on the server. I have tried to run this code locally by using gcloud auth application-default-account login and logging in with my G Suite admin account, and also my personal account (both are owners of the GCP project). After this failed, I did some research and realised that to enable OAuth2 to access my G Suite User data (I'm not really accessing anything by inserting a user?!?) I had to 'enable domain wide delegation' on the default service account, so I did this, I then downloaded the service account JSON and attempted to manually authorise with $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, but was still getting a 403. I then went one step further and followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority). Giving my Client ID access to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group and group.member.

After all this, I still get a 403 error.

With the application-default-credentials I get:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members?alt=json 
returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

When using the app engine default service account through .json with either activate-service-account or through the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, I get:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members?alt=json 
returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

(groupKey intentially censored)

In short, I have an app-engine default service account with domain wide delegation and have given it's client ID access to both roles required for the Directory API's member.insert() function, yet I am still not allowed to call the API as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? The only solution I have found so far is creating a new Service Account credential and using that instead of the default app engine one.

Comment: I never figured it out, but looking back on it, I imagine service accounts are the solution, at the time I was hesitant to use them, but now with a bit more experience it seems like the reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python to run a similar function locally using Google's google_auth_oauthlib to set up OAuth2 credentials

```
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
```